# Symbolic series

Tags: summation

Mathematica realises, of course, how to deal with symbolic series:

```
Sum[g[x]^k, {k, 0, ∞}]
(*Out: 1/(1 - g[x]) *)
```

I.e. it does not worry about values of `g[x]` around `1`. Next, when I write (don't ask me why I need this :-)) something like

```
Sum[Sum[Product[g[y], {y, xi}], {xi, {Table[x, k]}}], {k, 0, 10}]
```

I get the correct answer

```
1 + g[x] + g[x]^2 + g[x]^3 + g[x]^4 + g[x]^5 + g[x]^6 + g[x]^7 + g[x]^8 + g[x]^9 + g[x]^10
```

However,

```
Sum[Sum[Product[g[y], {y, xi}], {xi, {Table[x, k]}}], {k, 0, ∞}]
```

leads to the error

> During evaluation of In[3]:= Table::iterb: Iterator {k} does not have appropriate bounds.

The same will happen if I write, say,

```
Limit[Sum[Sum[Product[g[y], {y, xi}], {xi, {Table[x, k]}}], {k, 0, r}], r -> ∞]
```

Is it possible to ask *Mathematica* to compute `Sum` with such 'variable' upper limit?

Comment: Actually, let me ask you *exactly* that: why do you need to do this? What is your final goal? For instance, that first double sum expression seems a rather convoluted way to generate your desired output. Perhaps there is another approach that will remove the need to do what you are attempting altogether.

Comment: My aim was to consider the expression with infinite sum like the above but with `{Table[x, k]}` replaced by `Multisets[list, {k}]` where `Multisets` is taken from here [link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8115/). If `list={x}` then we have just `{Table[x, k]}`.

Comment: It doesn't help with your general problem, but note that the nested `Sum` can be written as `Sum[Product[g[y], {y, xi}], {k, 0, 10}, {xi, {Table[x, k]}}]`